# Second x axis in ggplotly with invisible second trace

Tags: r, plotly, ggplotly

I am trying to add a second x axis on a ggplotly plot, not to accommodate a second trace, but for better visualisation.

I have worked out that I do need to add a trace for it, but the question is how.  The examples I have found to add simple, transparent traces are not working for my plot which has factors on the y-axis.

Please take it as given that for my purposes I need to use ggplotly and need the second axis.  The example I am about to provide is just minimal, the real application has other requirements accommodated by ggplotly (as opposed to straight plotly or ggplot2).  Imagine if there were 100 different iris species that people were scrolling through, and that the top axis provides a good guide at first.  Using ggplot2, here is the example of what I would like to achieve with ggplotly:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

dat <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(meanSL = mean(Sepal.Length, na.rm = TRUE),
            count = n()) 


labels_dup = c("low", "medium", "high")
labels = c("low", "medium\n\nmeans to the right\nof this line are\nso cool", "high")
breaks = c(5,6,7)
limits = c(4,8)

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = reorder(as.character(Species),meanSL), y = meanSL)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 6, lty = 2) +
  coord_flip() +
  ggtitle("Means of sepal length by species") +
  
  theme_classic()+
  
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0.5))

p + scale_y_continuous(breaks = breaks, labels = labels, limits = limits, sec.axis = dup_axis(labels = labels_dup)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 4,label = paste0("n=",count)), size = 3)
```

and here is the output:

[image: minimal example]

Here is a start to the ggplotly solution:

```
ax <- list(
  side = "bottom",
  showticklabels = TRUE,
  range = limits,
  tickmode = "array", 
  tickvals = breaks,
  ticktext = labels)


ax2 <- list(
  overlaying = "x",
  side = "top",
  showticklabels = TRUE,
  range = limits,
  tickmode = "array", 
  tickvals = breaks,
  ticktext = labels_dup)

ggplotly(p) %>% 
  #<need a trace here e.g. add_lines, add_segment.  It could either be transparent, or use the vertical line or count text in the plot as shown in the example>  %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = ax,
    xaxis2 = ax2)
```

Edit:  Here is less minimal code that produces the warning when I use the suggested fix.  I use geom_pointrange instead of stat_summary for reasons related to the hover text:

```
library(boot)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

boot_sd <- function(x, fun=mean, R=1001) {
  fun <- match.fun(fun)
  bfoo <- function(data, idx) {
    fun(data[idx])
  }
  b <- boot(x, bfoo, R=R)
  sd(b$t)
}  

#Summarise the data for use with geom_pointrange and add some hover text for use with plotly:

dat <- iris %>% 
  mutate(flower_colour = c(rep(c("blue", "purple"), 25), rep(c("blue", "white"), 25), rep(c("white", "purple"), 25))) %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(meanSL = mean(Sepal.Length, na.rm = TRUE),
            countSL = n(),
            meSL = qt(0.975, countSL-1) * boot_sd(Sepal.Length, mean, 1001),
            lowerCI_SL = meanSL - meSL,
            upperCI_SL = meanSL + meSL,
            group = "Mean &\nConfidence Interval",
            colours_in_species = paste0(sort(unique(flower_colour)), collapse = ",")) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(colours_in_species = paste0("colours: ", colours_in_species))
  
  
  
#Some plotting variables
purple <- "#8f11e7"
plot_title_colour <- "#35373b"
axis_text_colour <- "#3c4042"
legend_text_colour <- "#3c4042"
annotation_colour <- "#3c4042"

labels_dup = c("low", "medium", "high")
labels = c("low", "medium\n\nmeans to the right\nof this line are\nso cool", "high")
breaks = c(5,6,7)
limits = c(4,8)

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = reorder(as.character(Species),meanSL), text = colours_in_species)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 4.2,label = paste0("n=",countSL)), color = annotation_colour, size = 3) +
 geom_pointrange(aes(y = meanSL, ymin=lowerCI_SL, ymax=upperCI_SL,color = group, fill = group), size = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = "#f4a01f", name = "Mean &\nConfidence Interval") +
  scale_color_manual(values = "#f4a01f", name = "Mean &\nConfidence Interval") +
  
  geom_hline(yintercept = 5, colour = "dark grey", linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 6, colour = purple, linetype = "dashed") +
  coord_flip() +
  
  ggtitle("Means of sepal length by species") +
  
  theme_classic()+
  
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=10, colour = axis_text_colour),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 0, colour = plot_title_colour), 
        legend.justification=c("right", "top"),
        legend.box.just = "center",
        legend.position ="top",
        legend.title.align = "left",
        legend.text=element_text(size = 8, hjust = 0.5, colour = legend_text_colour),
        legend.title=element_blank())



ax <- list(
  side = "top",
  showticklabels = TRUE,
  range = limits,
  tickmode = "array", 
  tickvals = breaks,
  ticktext = labels_dup)

ay <- list(
  side = "right")


ax2 <- list(
  overlaying = "x",
  side = "bottom",
  showticklabels = TRUE,
  range = limits,
  tickmode = "array", 
  tickvals = breaks,
  ticktext = labels_dup,
  tickfont = list(size = 11))




ggplotly(p, tooltip = 'text') %>% 
  add_markers(data = NULL, inherit = TRUE, xaxis = "x2") %>% 
  layout(
    xaxis = ax,
    xaxis2 = ax2,
    yaxis = ay,
    legend = list(orientation = "v", itemclick = FALSE, x = 1.2, y = 1.04),
    margin = list(t = 120, l = 60)
  )
```

and the warning is this:
Warning message:
'scatter' objects don't have these attributes: 'label'
Valid attributes include:
'type', 'visible', 'showlegend', 'legendgroup', 'opacity', 'name', 'uid', 'ids', 'customdata', 'meta', 'selectedpoints', 'hoverinfo', 'hoverlabel', 'stream', 'transforms', 'uirevision', 'x', 'x0', 'dx', 'y', 'y0', 'dy', 'stackgroup', 'orientation', 'groupnorm', 'stackgaps', 'text', 'texttemplate', 'hovertext', 'mode', 'hoveron', 'hovertemplate', 'line', 'connectgaps', 'cliponaxis', 'fill', 'fillcolor', 'marker', 'selected', 'unselected', 'textposition', 'textfont', 'r', 't', 'error_x', 'error_y', 'xcalendar', 'ycalendar', 'xaxis', 'yaxis', 'idssrc', 'customdatasrc', 'metasrc', 'hoverinfosrc', 'xsrc', 'ysrc', 'textsrc', 'texttemplatesrc', 'hovertextsrc', 'hovertemplatesrc', 'textpositionsrc', 'rsrc', 'tsrc', 'key', 'set', 'frame', 'transforms', '_isNestedKey', '_isSimpleKey', '_isGraticule', '_bbox'

Comment: Note I have just added a text geom to the example that is used in my original application and could be used for a trace - but I don't know how to add it the plotly way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get it working by just adding:

`add_markers(data = NULL, inherit = TRUE, xaxis = "x2")`

And I did also set the `tickfont` size of your second axis to `11` to match the font size of your original axis.

Although it is working, sometimes changing the zoom (especially when clicking "autoscale") will mess up the scales of the x axes so that they are not in sync anymore. Probably the best option is to limit the available options in the icon bar.

Here is your edited code put into a running shiny app:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

dat <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(meanSL = mean(Sepal.Length, na.rm = TRUE),
            count = n()) 


labels_dup = c("low", "medium", "high")
labels = c("low", "medium\n\nmeans to the right\nof this line are\nso cool", "high")
breaks = c(5,6,7)
limits = c(4,8)

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = reorder(as.character(Species),meanSL), y = meanSL)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 6, lty = 2) +
  coord_flip() +
  ggtitle("Means of sepal length by species") +
  
  theme_classic() +
  
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0.5))

p + scale_y_continuous(breaks = breaks, labels = labels, limits = limits, sec.axis = dup_axis(labels = labels_dup)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 4,label = paste0("n=",count)), size = 3)


ax <- list(
  side = "bottom",
  showticklabels = TRUE,
  range = limits,
  tickmode = "array", 
  tickvals = breaks,
  ticktext = labels)


ax2 <- list(
  overlaying = "x",
  side = "top",
  showticklabels = TRUE,
  range = limits,
  tickmode = "array", 
  tickvals = breaks,
  ticktext = labels_dup,
  tickfont = list(size = 11)) # I added this line


shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
      plotlyOutput("plot")
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    
    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
      
      ggplotly(p) %>% 
        add_markers(data = NULL, inherit = TRUE, xaxis = "x2") %>% # new line
        layout(
          xaxis = ax,
          xaxis2 = ax2)
    })
  }
)
```

**Update**

Below is a running shiny app with the additional example code. Although it is showing a warning that

> Warning: 'scatter' objects don't have these attributes: 'label'

the plot is displayed correctly with both x axes.

I assume that the plot not showing correctly is unrelated to the warning above.

```
library(boot)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

boot_sd <- function(x, fun=mean, R=1001) {
  fun <- match.fun(fun)
  bfoo <- function(data, idx) {
    fun(data[idx])
  }
  b <- boot(x, bfoo, R=R)
  sd(b$t)
}  

#Summarise the data for use with geom_pointrange and add some hover text for use with plotly:

dat <- iris %>% 
  mutate(flower_colour = c(rep(c("blue", "purple"), 25), rep(c("blue", "white"), 25), rep(c("white", "purple"), 25))) %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(meanSL = mean(Sepal.Length, na.rm = TRUE),
            countSL = n(),
            meSL = qt(0.975, countSL-1) * boot_sd(Sepal.Length, mean, 1001),
            lowerCI_SL = meanSL - meSL,
            upperCI_SL = meanSL + meSL,
            group = "Mean &\nConfidence Interval",
            colours_in_species = paste0(sort(unique(flower_colour)), collapse = ",")) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(colours_in_species = paste0("colours: ", colours_in_species))



#Some plotting variables
purple <- "#8f11e7"
plot_title_colour <- "#35373b"
axis_text_colour <- "#3c4042"
legend_text_colour <- "#3c4042"
annotation_colour <- "#3c4042"

labels_dup = c("low", "medium", "high")
labels = c("low", "medium\n\nmeans to the right\nof this line are\nso cool", "high")
breaks = c(5,6,7)
limits = c(4,8)

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = reorder(as.character(Species),meanSL), text = colours_in_species)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 4.2,label = paste0("n=",countSL)), color = annotation_colour, size = 3) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(y = meanSL, ymin=lowerCI_SL, ymax=upperCI_SL,color = group, fill = group), size = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = "#f4a01f", name = "Mean &\nConfidence Interval") +
  scale_color_manual(values = "#f4a01f", name = "Mean &\nConfidence Interval") +
  
  geom_hline(yintercept = 5, colour = "dark grey", linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 6, colour = purple, linetype = "dashed") +
  coord_flip() +
  
  ggtitle("Means of sepal length by species") +
  
  theme_classic()+
  
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=10, colour = axis_text_colour),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 0, colour = plot_title_colour), 
        legend.justification=c("right", "top"),
        legend.box.just = "center",
        legend.position ="top",
        legend.title.align = "left",
        legend.text=element_text(size = 8, hjust = 0.5, colour = legend_text_colour),
        legend.title=element_blank())



ax <- list(
  side = "top",
  showticklabels = TRUE,
  range = limits,
  tickmode = "array", 
  tickvals = breaks,
  ticktext = labels_dup)

ay <- list(
  side = "right")


ax2 <- list(
  overlaying = "x",
  side = "bottom",
  showticklabels = TRUE,
  range = limits,
  tickmode = "array", 
  tickvals = breaks,
  ticktext = labels_dup,
  tickfont = list(size = 11))



shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    plotlyOutput("plot")
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    
    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
      
      ggplotly(p, tooltip = 'text') %>% 
        add_markers(data = NULL, inherit = TRUE, xaxis = "x2") %>% 
        layout(
          xaxis = ax,
          xaxis2 = ax2,
          yaxis = ay,
          legend = list(orientation = "v", itemclick = FALSE, x = 1.2, y = 1.04),
          margin = list(t = 120, l = 60)
        )
      
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks.  This gives me a warning "No scatter mode specifed:
  Setting the mode to markers
  Read more about this attribute -> https://plot.ly/r/reference/#scatter-mode" which is similar to the warning I get with other attempts.  In this minimal example it warns but works.  In my actual plot, which is in shiny, I get the warning "Warning: 'scatter' objects don't have these attributes: 'label' "which I think is related. The second axis doesn't appear. I will give the bounty to this answer if no other answers come along, with the caveat that it produces a warning.

Comment: @racho: We can change `add_trace` to `add_markers` to get the same result without warning. If your problem still persists, we would need a less minimal example which reproduces said error. My guess is, that your original plot is much more complex, so you could try adding more complexity to the example above until the error shows up.

Comment: Thanks, @TimTeaFan.  I have provided a more complex example if you care to look.

Comment: @racho: I looked at the more complex example and although I can reproduce the warning message, the plot is still correctly rendered showing both x axes. I assume that the problem with the second x axis is not related to the warning. Can you try to add more original code to the example until the second axis vanishes? My guess is that some specification either in your `ggplot` or your `plotly` calls is overriding the second x axis.